# bookshelf.js recursive query plus ordering

Tags: recursion, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I've found one example of recursive tree fetch but ordering does not work.  What is the best way to fetch all items recursively with ordering at each level?

Model

```
knex.schema.createTable('items', function (table) {
  table.increments();
  table.string('title');
  table.integer('parent');
  table.integer('order');
});

var Item = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'items',
  items: function() {
    return this.hasMany(Item, 'parent');
  }
});
```

Recursive but only to certain amount of level, all would be preferred instead of specifying depth.  This works but doesn't order related items correctly.  [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540746/accessing-nested-relations-in-bookshelf-js)

```
Item.query({where: {parent: null}, orderBy: 'id'})
  .fetchAll(
    {
      withRelated: ['items.items.items.items.items'],
      orderBy: 'id'
    });
```

**Edit**

I'm updating this with a recursive query that works for SQLite (note I'm using id for ordering because my bad choice of column name).  Solution maybe to use bookshelf for crud operations and a raw query to populate objects that I need.

```
with recursive tc( i )
as ( select id FROM items WHERE parent IS NULL
     UNION SELECT id FROM items, tc WHERE items.parent = tc.i ORDER BY id
)
select * FROM items WHERE id IN tc;
```